# Using invalidate() java.lang.NullPointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, invalidation

I need to implement image editor project. basically, I need to add some icons,text over an input image then export to final image.

The problem is, when I add a new image to the view (via options menu) and do `invalidate();` to show the changes  I get a `java.lang.NullPointerexception` in method `onDraw()`...

any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

**PhotoSortrActivity.java**

```
public class PhotoSortrActivity extends Activity {

PhotoSortrView photoSorter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
    photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
    // setContentView(photoSorter);

    setContentView(R.layout.foto);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    this.addContentView(photoSorter, params);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.foto, menu);
    return true;
    /** true -> el menú ya está visible */
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mascara:
        // lanzarAcercaDe(null);

        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast por defecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();

                    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        photoSorter.addImage(R.drawable.catarina);          
        break;
    }
    return true;
    /** true -> consumimos el item, no se propaga */
}
```

**PhotoShortView.java**

```
public class PhotoSortrView extends View implements MultiTouchObjectCanvas<MultiTouchEntity> {
//private static final int[] IMAGES = { R.drawable.m74hubble, R.drawable.catarina, R.drawable.tahiti, R.drawable.sunset, R.drawable.lake };

private ArrayList<MultiTouchEntity> mImages = new ArrayList<MultiTouchEntity>();

// --

private MultiTouchController<MultiTouchEntity> multiTouchController = 
    new MultiTouchController<MultiTouchEntity>(this);

// --

private PointInfo currTouchPoint = new PointInfo();

private boolean mShowDebugInfo = true;

private static final int UI_MODE_ROTATE = 1, UI_MODE_ANISOTROPIC_SCALE = 2;

private int mUIMode = UI_MODE_ROTATE;

// --

private Paint mLinePaintTouchPointCircle = new Paint();

private static final float SCREEN_MARGIN = 100;

private int width, height, displayWidth, displayHeight;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public PhotoSortrView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    init(context);
}

public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();


            // THIS CALL WORKS!!
    addImage( R.drawable.m74hubble);


    mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    //setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    this.displayWidth = res.getConfiguration().orientation == 
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Math.max(metrics.widthPixels,
        metrics.heightPixels) : Math.min(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
    this.displayHeight = res.getConfiguration().orientation == 
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Math.min(metrics.widthPixels,
        metrics.heightPixels) : Math.max(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);

}

/** Called by activity's onResume() method to load the images */
public void loadImages(Context context) {
    int n = mImages.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        float cx = SCREEN_MARGIN + (float) 
            (Math.random() * (displayWidth - 2 * SCREEN_MARGIN));
        float cy = SCREEN_MARGIN + (float) 
            (Math.random() * (displayHeight - 2 * SCREEN_MARGIN));
        mImages.get(i).load(context, cx, cy);
    }
}

// añade una nueva imagen al array
public void addImage(int image){
    Resources res = this.getContext().getResources();
    mImages.add(new ImageEntity(image, res));
    //postInvalidate();
    invalidate(); // ERROR



}

/** Called by activity's onPause() method to free memory used for loading the images */
public void unloadImages() {
    int n = mImages.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mImages.get(i).unload();
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int n = mImages.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mImages.get(i).draw(canvas); //NULL POINTER
    if (mShowDebugInfo)
        drawMultitouchDebugMarks(canvas);
}
```

.
.
.

**LogCat**

```
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at org.android.eboliza_esta_foto.utils.controller.ImageEntity.draw(ImageEntity.java:59)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at org.android.eboliza_esta_foto.PhotoSortrView.onDraw(PhotoSortrView.java:137)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13803)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13687)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13685)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13685)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13806)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2239)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2593)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2340)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5338)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-12 20:20:20.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16798):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: this.invalidate ? postInvalidate ?

Comment: The error is in `ImageEntity.java` on line number 59

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addImage(Context context,int image){
    Resources res = this.getContext().getResources();
    mImages.add(new ImageEntity(image, res));
    loadImages(context); // add this
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.